# Randomly choosing a user in a text channel

Tags: javascript, random, bots, discord, discord.js

I made a discord bot using discord.js and it has some useful commands to it. I want to add one more, one that will tag a random person from the text channel I used that command. For example, if I use that command in #test123 channel, it will tag a random person that has test123 as a role.

Comment: You have to show what you tried to get this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works for Discord.js v12/v13:

```js
const {Client} = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client()

client.on('message', async ({author, channel, content, guild}) => {
  if (
    // author of message is a bot
    author.bot ||
    // message is in a DM
    !guild ||
    // message doesn't start with #
    !content.startsWith('#')
  ) return

  // gets rid of the #
  const name = content.slice(1)

  try {
    // uncomment this out if you don't want people to be able to do this with @everyone
    // the backslash stops the bot from pinging everyone
    // if (name === '@everyone') return await channel.send("You can't do this with \\@everyone!")

    const role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === name)
    if (!role) return await channel.send(`${name} is not a valid role!`)
    if (!role.members.size) return await channel.send(`There are no members with the role ${role}.`)

    // discord.js automatically tags/mentions a member if it is converted to a string
    await channel.send(`${role.members.random()}`)
  } catch (error) {
    // you could also send a message or something
    console.error(error)
  }
})

client.login('your token')
```

For v11 just replace

```js
    const role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === name)
```

with

```js
    const role = guild.roles.find(r => r.name === name)
```